# Generate Google Protobuf TimeStamp from .Net System.DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

How to convert .Net System.DateTime to google Protobuf TimeStamp when forming a protobuf message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use protobuf's Timestamp.FromDateTime. Following is the example of converting DateTime.Now to proto timestamp type.

```
Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp protoTimestamp 
    = Google.Protobuf.WellKnownTypes.Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
```

This is the official reference [link](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/well-known-types/timestamp#public-static-functions)

Answer (score 3):

Timestamp only works with UTC. So you may do this:

```
Timestamp.FromDateTime(DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Now, DateTimeKind.Utc)));
```